# Directional/menu selector component name

Tags: button, selector

I'm new to eletronics and I don't know some component names I need to use to find some. Example, I'm looking for a 'kit' or a button set like this to use on a dashboard panel project I'm working on:
[image]

Is there a proper name for this component?

Comment: Try "navigation keypad" but I think you'll be disappointed. They're just five momentary switches mounted on the PCB with custom moulded buttons mounted in the panel. Consider the use of an encoder with push-button "select". This will be a lot simpler mechanically.

Comment: Look at the Grayhill website for leads. Consider a selector joystick

Comment: Push-button select? Yeah, so, the idea is to actrually have the 'circle' of buttons around the middle one. Being the arrows the direction I want to put up the shields and the center being a reset option. Btw, this is for gaming, Star Citizen.

Comment: found this: https://www.newark.com/mec/navikitth09wl/switch-kit-spno-black/dp/53M9433?st=navigation%20switch

Comment: You've also found a gap in the market for "[button clusters](https://www.google.com/search?q=button+cluster&tbm=isch)".

Comment: Another option is a 10kOhm 23 deg. thumb pointer then a separate OK button. https://www.mouser.ca/new/alps-electric/alps-electric-rkjx-thumbpointer/

Comment: do you want to be able to press all five buttons at once?

Comment: @jsotola nope, it would be more like a menu navigation thing...